# How can I turn a list of pairs of coordinates in string form into a list of pairs of floats?

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

I'm reading in a list of coordinates from a kml file giving me this output:

```
['-73.9972973,40.7075148', ..., '-73.9850235,40.7900946']
```

(Imagine the ... as a lot more coordinates similar to the first and last)
I'm using the following code to try to accomplish this but it won't work.

```
manhattanCoords = []

for coord in coords:
    pair = [float(s) for s in coord.strip().split(", ")]
    manhattanCoords.append(pair)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Manhattan_Coords_Extract.py", line 12, in <module>
    pair = [float(s) for s in coord.strip().split(", ")]
  File "Manhattan_Coords_Extract.py", line 12, in <listcomp>
    pair = [float(s) for s in coord.strip().split(", ")]
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-73.9972973,40.7075148'
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Your strings don't contain `", "` (note the space), so can't be split on it.

Comment: The KML file I'm reading from is the same way without spaces, so I'm not sure how to read it in otherwise.

Comment: If what you have separating the numbers is a comma and no space, split on a comma and no space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .split(",") not .split(", ")

(no space)

Thanks to Zero Piraeus for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate through your list, and `.split()` on `','` characters. Then you can convert them to `float`. In a list comprehension, that would be the following.

```
l = ['-123.456,532.643', '245.234,241.678', '345.342,344.342']
coords = [map(float,i.split(',')) for i in l]

>>> coords
[[-123.456, 532.643], [245.234, 241.678], [345.342, 344.342]]
```

Comment: This only returns a list of map objects for me?

Comment: No. `map` is a function that means "perform this operation on each member of the list", so I am using it to convert the split `string` values to `float`. So the returned list `coords` is a `list` of `list` of `float`.